# Can LWJGL support multiple displays

Tags: lwjgl

Can LWJGL support multiple displays either as separated windows or as part of an AWT Window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [bug report](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/issues/24) about multiple displays in LWJGL:

> This is one of the primary features planned for [LWJGL 3.0](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3). You can
>   actually already experiment with multiple windows if you're feeling
>   adventurous and want to try 3.0, see [this post](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php/topic,4800.msg26641.html#msg26641) for an example.
>
> Do keep in mind that LWJGL 3.0 is at a pre-alpha stage and all APIs
>   may be subject to change.
>
> Closing this issue as there's no plan to implement multiple Displays
>   in LWJGL 2.x.

So, **if you're using version 2.x, no, LWJGL cannot support multiple displays**. While it looks like there might be plans to do so in the future, I wouldn't plan on it for your own game, and I wouldn't start using the alpha for your development either.

Comment: Well i wanted it for my map-tool not the actual game, but thanks, I searched the webs and didn't find this. :D

Comment: Oh? It's the first search result in Google for "LWJGL support multiple displays". Also, it doesn't really matter what you're using it for, if you want multiple displays, you can't do it with LWJGL 2.x.

Comment: I have a different approach on searching Google. I don't ask him if it supports, I instead ask him how to do it. My mistake. :D